# d3 force directed graph remove text cursor

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I add text to a node in a d3 force directed graph layout, the mouse pointer changes to a text cursor when I hover over the node. Is there a way to avoid this and always have it remain the regular pointer?

Normal Pointer:

[image: Normal Pointer]

Text Cursor:

[image]

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/50v4px1m/4/) with the code used to produce these images, along with the code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var drawGraph = function(graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('gnode', true)
  .call(force.drag);

  var node = gnodes.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

   var labels = gnodes.append("text")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
              .attr('font-size', 8.0)
              .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
              .attr('y', 2.5)
              .attr('fill', d3.rgb(50,50,50))
              .attr('class', 'node-label')
              .append("svg:title")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                  gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')';
                  });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your text elements:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This will prevent any mouse events for the text elements, i.e. the cursor won't change but you also won't be able to select the text.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/50v4px1m/5/).