# d3 force directed graph don't select text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to stop to text from being selected when the drag behavior is turned off in a force directed graph?

The drag behavior is turned off using these lines:

```
svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
.on('mousedown.drag', null);
```

The pointer remains a pointer, rather than a cursor (as per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088631/d3-force-directed-graph-remove-text-cursor)). But dragging still ends up changing the pointer to a cursor and starts to select text. Is there a way to avoid this so no text is selected when dragging?

[Here's a link to the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/kcv4opLe/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) seems to do the trick. This requires adding the following definition to the css file:

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

And adding the `noselect` class to the gnodes:

```
  var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('gnode', true)
  .classed('noselect', true)
  .call(force.drag);
```

Answer (score 3):

Disable the pointer-events on the entire groupnode. So instead of:

```
text {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

use:

```
.gnode {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being an idiot, but this doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/50v4px1m/10/. There also this other problem that when I disable the pointer events on the whole gnode, then I can't get things like mouseup or mousemove, right?